# android webview just can not load some specific wap?

Tags: android, android-webview

Here show my code:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    /**
     * 自定义网页加载
     */
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
        } else
            view.loadUrl(url);

        return true;
    }
});

String url1 = "http://192.168.72.203:8080/wap-pc/toOtherLogin?appSource=0";
JavaScriptInterface jsInterface = new JavaScriptInterface();
webView.addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface, "loginInterface");

webView.loadUrl(url1)
```

It just shows a blank page.  Can anyone help me to resolve this?